# How can i download doc or pdf file from UIWebView

Tags: iphone

I can show url to UIWebView.But How can i download and save a file from UIWebView to folder When the download link is clicked.

Answer (score 3):

Implement `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` in your web view delegate. If you receive a request to a file that you are interested in, return `NO` from that method and start a separate `NSURLConnection` to download the file into an `NSData` object that you can then save.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationtype
{

    // Will execute this block only when links are clicked
    if( navigationtype == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked )
    {
          ...//create NSURLConnection object and save the downloaded bytes in NSData in 
          connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    }
}
```